I don't have "version of the schema included in the schema dump"
I am upgrading my app from Rails 6.1 to Rails 7.0, and in the upgrading instructions they made an important note about:

ensure that the version of the schema is included in the schema dump.

Like in here:
ActiveRecord::Schema[6.1].define(version: 2022_01_28_123512) do
  # ...
end

But in my schema.rb I don't have such a version of the schema:
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2024_05_05_142804) do
  # ...
end

Even after running rails app:update and rails db:schema:dump.
I have tried to add the [6.1] by hand and then run rails db:schema:dump , but the result is that the version number is removed again.
Is this important? and how I can solve it?

This was added in v7.0.2:

Dump the database schema containing the current Rails version...

https://github.com/rails/rails/releases/tag/v7.0.2

Before that you do not get a schema version:
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(#{define_params}) do
...

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb#L90
